# First letter doesn't change to capital when using a lot of spaces between words

Tags: java

I want to capitalize the first letter of every word. When I'm typing `test test test` it's changing to `Test Test Test`, but if I use a lot of spaces between `test         test test`, it's not changing first letters to capital. How should I change my code to work properly?

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        try{
            String test = reader.readLine();
            String[] testSplit = test.split( " " );
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int I =0 ; I < testSplit.length ; I ++){
                String capitalVer = capitalizeFirstLetter(testSplit[I]);
                if( I != 0 ){
                    sb.append(" ");
                }
                sb.append(capitalVer);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception es)
        {

        }
    }



    public static String capitalizeFirstLetter(final String string)
    {
        if (string == null || string.equals("") )
            throw new NullPointerException("no string ");

        return Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(0)) + string.substring(1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your code, as shown, doesn't produce the (undesired) output you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First of all you mean to split on spaces:

```
test.split( " " )
```

Secondly, when you hit empty strings, your `capitalizeFirstLetter()` is throwing an exception. However, since you are catching and ignoring the exception, you never see it.

The reason you have empty strings is that you are using a single space as a delimiter, so splitting `"    "`, for example, results in 5 empty strings (between the spaces). You can either modify `capitalizeFirstLetter()` to handle empty strings, or split on, say, `\s+` to collapse whitespace -- note, however, that the latter will collapse consecutive whitespace in your output.

Adding a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testSplit))` is a good way to see exactly what your array contains.

The moral here is: **Handle exceptions properly; don't just swallow them and ignore them.** By catching exceptions and not even printing information about them when they occur, you've effectively disabled any information that could have let you track down this issue.

By the way, `NullPointerException` isn't really appropriate for an empty string there; an `IllegalArgumentException` might be more descriptive.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand.

Comment: @Predict_it What part don't you understand? You have a `try...catch` block to catch exceptions. You just ignore the exception, though. Your code is throwing an exception but because you are ignoring it, you never see it. This means your code is *trying* to tell you what is wrong, but you can not see the error, and so you are confused.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: @Predict_it The answers posted to this question have described your problem in detail and given you all the information you need to solve it. There is not much more I can offer aside from doing your work for you, which I will not do.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String[] testSplit = test.split( "" );
```

with:

```
String[] testSplit = test.split("\\s+");
```

That way, the split is made with an arbitrary number of spaces. However, it won't retain how many spaces were between each word.

Comment: this putting words together but i want to keep that split between words

Comment: Then you're probably better off not using a regex to split the String, since this won't retain that kind of information. Probably better off putting the `String` into a `StringBuffer`, and looping through it and checking if a letter is the first of a word, and then capitalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

`String[] testSplit = test.split( "" );` should be `String[] testSplit = test.split( " " );`

and you might want to trim your results, so `capitalizeFirstLetter(testSplit[i].trim());` to remove whitespace on the left and on the right.

Unless you want to preserve the whitespace, then you would need a different approach.

EDIT:

If you want the whitespace to stay, in your `capitalizeFirstLetter` method, go through each character and check whether it is a letter. If it is not a letter, append it to an output String (better StringBuilder). If it is a letter, capitalize it, append it, append the rest and return.

EDIT:

Your capitalizeFirstLetter could look like this:

```
public static String capitalizeFirstLetter (String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // use a StringBuilder to construct the output
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i); // get current character
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) { // if character is a letter
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c)); // capitalize it
            sb.append(s.substring(i+1)); // append the rest of the string
            return sb.toString(); // return result
        } else {
            sb.append(c); // if character is not a letter, append character
        }
    }
    return sb.toString(); // return result
}
```

Comment: Splitting the string like this doesn't solve the no-capitalization-with-multiple-spaces issue the OP described.

Comment: @Predict_it look at the edited answer, I have included the code to what I described before, in case it wasn't clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple, does the whole job:

```
public static String capAllFirstLetters (String s) {
  String capped = "";
  char prev = ' ';
  for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    capped += "" + (Character.isWhitespace(prev) ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c);
    prev = c;
  } 
  return capped;
}
```

Or if you prefer StringBuilder:

```
public static String capAllFirstLetters (String s) {
  StringBuilder capped = new StringBuilder();
  char prev = ' ';
  for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    capped.append(Character.isWhitespace(prev) ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : c);
    prev = c;
  } 
  return capped.toString();
}
```